# Why system("color 3") is "global"?

Tags: c++

Code:

```
int print()
{
   system("color 2");                 //paint the "one"
   std::cout << "one" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   print();                           //prints "one"
   system("color 3");                 //paint the "two"
   std::cout << "two" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I'm a newbie programmer, and I want to write a simple code which prints text in different colors. The thing is, when I compile it, cout “one” and “two” are the same color as I don't expect. However, when I change the color in int main(), cout “one” take color from int main() forgetting about the “color2” from function print().

And my question is, how to avoid that “global” system(“color 3”)? What exactly happened? Is it a good method to color a text?

Comment: You should not be using `system` - That is running an external program. Use the curses library instead

Comment: This is not a C++ question, and may not be well received here. I honestly don't know where "color 2" or "color 3" come from, likely something from your operating system, which you didn't mention, and is not C++-related. I guess maybe you need to "color 0" or something to return your terminal to the original color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to write a simple code which prints text in different colors.

Your question is not C++ related and is [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) (and hardware) specific. Some computers don't have color screens (and some don't have any screens at all, but still provide a standard conforming C++ implementation, e.g. some web, network, internet server, IoT device, etc...)

We don't know what `color` is or does. It could even be some of your private program somewhere in your [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (used by the command processor working for `system`). BTW, practically speaking, running an external program to simply change colors is inefficient.

Standard C++ does not know about colors at all. Only about [standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).

Maybe your program is outputting on some terminal capable of [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (but you need to check that - and with command [pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) or [redirections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) your *stdout* or `std::cout` is not even a terminal!). Then you might use something like

```
#define ESCAPE_BOLD "\033[1m"
#define ESCAPE_NORMAL "\033[0m"
```

and later

```
std::cout << "Here is something " << ESCAPE_BOLD << "in bold" 
          << ESCAPE_NORMAL << std::endl;
```

I leave you to find out the escape sequence for red.

Maybe you want to code some [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) application. Then use a widget toolkit like [Qt](http://qt.io/).

Perhaps you want to code a textual interface. Then consider some library for that, e.g. [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

Maybe you want some web interface (so learn more about web technologies), then use some [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) server library like [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) or [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/).

Comment: -1 Just google COLOR command...
It will show up as DOS builin thing.

Comment: The -1 was a bit unfair

Comment: This is not an answer. To ask for clarification leave a comment under the question.

Comment: @nwp I think it's a fine answer. It responds to "Does it good method to color a text?" with good advice and examples.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `color` refers to builtin in windows `cmd.exe` (or DOS builtin). If so, the documentation explains it clearly

> The COLOR command will change the color of all the text in the window.

https://ss64.com/nt/color.html

So what happens is

1. You change the window color to green
2. Print "one"
3. Change the window color to aqua - this changes also already printed "one"
4. Print "two"

You can check if I'm right by adding some delay between changing color (like `std::cin.get()`)